# can not implement star rating system in jsp

Tags: jsp, web-applications

I'm writing a small web application with Java.  I want to create a rating system for books in library when end-user view detail of book and rating for this book. i use 
  http://tech.pro/tutorial/931/how-to-build-a-star-ratings-jquery-plugin to implement it.
my jsp page is:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Star rating demo</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../css/jquery.ratings.css" />
    <script src="../js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/jquery.ratings.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/example.js"></script>
    <s:head/>

</head>
<body>

    <div id="example-1"></div> <br />
    Your Rating: <span id="example-rating-1">not set</span>
    <br /><br />
    <div id="example-2"></div> <br />
    Your Rating: <span id="example-rating-2">not set</span>
    <h1><s:text name="welcome" /></h1>

</body>
```

but Stars are not displayed in browser.I use Netbeans and create folders inside WEB-INF with names 'css' and 'js'.inside of css folder I have:

> css --> jquery.ratings.css   and  pictures for stars

and in js folder:

> js --> jquery.ratings.js    and   jquery-1.3.2.min.js   and   example.js

but when i run the app, Stars are not displayed. can anyone help me?

Excuse for my English.

Comment: Everything under WEB-INF can't be accessed from the outside. This directory contains files that must be kept private to the webapp. Don't put your CSS and JS files there.

Comment: thank for your explain. so how should i set the file path in jsp? i put css and js folder outside of WEB-INF.how set the path for them in jsp page?

Comment: I think we only access to folders inside WEB-INF in jsp page. Is it wrong؟

Answer (score 0):

CSS files and JS files must be downloaded by the browser. And WEB-INF is precisely a directory from which nothing can be downloaded by the prower: it contains the configuration, class and jar fiels that must stay private to the webapp. So you shouldn't put those files in WEB-INF.

If the URL displayed in the browser address bar is `http://localhost/myApp/foo/bar.jsp`, and the relative URL you have in the JSP is `../js/example.js`, then the browser will download the JS file at the URL `http://localhost/myApp/js/example.js`. So in that case, the JS file should be in a directory named `js`, located right under the root of your webapp.

If the URL is `http://localhost/myApp/foo/bar/baz/bang/bing.jsp`, then the browser will look for the JS file at the URL `http://localhost/myApp/foo/bar/baz/js/example.js`. My advice: don't use relative paths for your JS and CSS files (and for everything else, in fact). Use absolute paths:

```
<script src="<c:url value='/js/example.js'/>"></script>
```

That way, whatever the URL of the page, the browser will always look for the JS file at the URL `http://localhost/myApp/js/example.js`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I change the file path but does not know js and css files.

Comment: If you want more help, you need to elaborate a little bit. Just saying "it doesn't work" doesn't help at all.